# How should I test if a component is defined in declarations of the SharedModule in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, integration-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to write a test with Karma in Angular for a module that checks the existence of @NgModule declarations properties.
this is my SharedModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationHeaderComponent } from './navigation-header/navigation-header.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [

  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and I want to check NavigationHeaderComponent exist or not in declarations with a spec.ts test file.
How can I do this?

Comment: That seems like the wrong idea for a unit test. That sounds more like an e2e or integration test. You might look into that instead.

Comment: It is 100% wrong for unit testing, but it seems like a good idea for integration testing @MatthewGreen

Comment: So what's the reason for the jasmine related tags? I think you need a different test runner to handle this. Angular comes with Protractor support when you add e2e to your project.